# Why is Jekyll not working with live reload option?

Tags: jekyll, livereload, webrick

Jekyll had been working fine for me about 50 times live-reloading.

However, now, each time I want to use live-reload option it throws this error once and once again, many times:

```
$ jekyll serve -l
Configuration file: MY_SITE/_config.yml
            Source: MY_SITE
       Destination: MY_SITE/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.473 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '.../docs'
LiveReload address: http://127.0.0.1:35729
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
        LiveReload: Browser connected
      Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2024-02-13 09:26:26
                    CHANGED_FILE_PATH
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    ...done in 0.235080909 second
[2024-02-13 09:26:26] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:30 
    HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
    HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
    HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/server.rb:310:in `block in start_thread'
```

And it does not regenerate anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using docker!

```
# docs/Dockerfile

FROM ruby:3.3 as base

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential apt-utils libpq-dev # nodejs

COPY . /docker/app/

WORKDIR /docker/app/docs

RUN gem install bundler

CMD bundle install && jekyll serve
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  jekyll:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docs/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/docker/app
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
      - "35729:35729"
```

```yaml
# docs/_config.yml
host: 0.0.0.0
```